# SQL Pivot query puts same value in every column

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I need some help in creating the query using pivot which I have created but I am facing issue that when I apply aggregate funtion on any column query puts that value for every column.

```
create table #skillsTemp
(
    RowNumber INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ResourceId INT,
    Caption VARCHAR(MAX),
    SubPracticeName VARCHAR(1000),
    SkillName VARCHAR(MAX),
    IsActive BIT,
    IsCoreSkill INT,
    TrainingTypeId INT
)


INSERT INTO #skillsTemp (ResourceId, Caption, SubPracticeName, SkillName, IsActive, IsCoreSkill, TrainingTypeId)

SELECT Resource.ResourceId, Resource.Caption, SubPracticeName, SkillName, IsActive, MAX(IsCoreSkill) IsCoreSkill,  ResourceAttribute.TrainingTypeId FROM Resource INNER JOIN
SubPractice ON SubPractice.SubPracticeId = Resource.SubPracticeId LEFT OUTER JOIN
SkillMaster ON SkillMaster.SubPracticeId = SubPractice.SubPracticeId LEFT OUTER JOIN
ResourceAttribute ON ResourceAttribute.ResourceId = Resource.ResourceId 

WHERE ResourceTypeId = 6 AND Resource.IsDeleted = 0 AND SkillMaster.SubPracticeId = 1
GROUP BY Resource.ResourceId, Resource.Caption, SkillName, SubPracticeName, ResourceAttribute.TrainingTypeId, IsActive


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @secondaryCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.SkillName)
            FROM #skillsTemp c
            where IsCoreSkill = 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
SET @secondaryCols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.SkillName)
    FROM #skillsTemp c
    WHERE IsCoreSkill = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT  Caption, ''A'' AS Priority, ' + @cols + ', ' + @secondaryCols + '  from 
            (
                select ResourceId
                    , Caption
                    , SkillName,
                    IsActive
                from #skillsTemp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(ResourceId) 
                for SkillName in (' + @cols + ', ' + @secondaryCols + ')
            ) p'
```

SELECT @query

EXECUTE( @query)

This is my whole query. It returns 2 records but it fill ReourceId at every column as value. What I need is If Fico have some then It should show to Fico and to particular instead of showing to all columns.

> Caption, Priority, FICO, Cash Mgt are columns, while X and Y are different values.

Actual output:

Caption               Priority  FICO    Cash Mgt. 
Shreesh Testing         A       28983   28983
Test   Test             A       28966   28966

Expected Output:
Caption             Priority    FICO    Cash Mgt.
Shreesh Testing       A          X         0
Test Test             A          0         Y

Comment: put sample input and expected output.

Comment: `print @query` or `select @query` prior to `execute(@query)` so we can see the code generated.